# My project files are not included into apk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am always getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.ooolpi.lpiapp.ui.activity.MainActivity`. But I have such class. Later I discovered that my project files are missing from apk.

My build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        //  classpath 'org.robolectric.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.10.1'
        //classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}
//apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/donnfelker/mvn-repo/raw/master/' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "ru.ooolpi.lpiapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../devcert.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
            keyAlias 'dev'
            keyPassword '123456'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        //disable 'InvalidPackage'
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true // this is default for release
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to build with Android Studio and just with gradlew. Result is the same - my files are not included into apk.

**Update:**
My project structure

[image: project structure]

Comment: I think its happening because of the pro-guard enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used different versions for dagger and it's compiler.

How it was:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.0.1'
```

It should look like:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

So, Android Studio refused to highlight issues in my code (I don't know why these things are related).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your proguard config file.

Make sure you don't strip off any class that you use in your apk. To manually keep the classes, add these lines:

```
-keep class ru.ooolpi.lpiapp.** { *; }
-dontwarn ru.ooolpi.lpiapp.**
```

Comment: It didn't helped. And the thing is that proguard disabled for debug build which does not work either.